# Which version of Microsoft .Net should I use for Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7

I am new to .Net framework.

I want to develop a PC application, probably in .net framework 2.0. I will create an installer and want to run it in another machine which has windows 7 OS.

Which is the .net version i need to install on windows 7, so that I can run my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 will already have .NET framework installed. So as long as you are targeting framework version 2 or greater, you only need to install your application.

As other answers have mentioned Windows 7 comes with version 3.5 already installed.
It should also be noted that version 3.5 uses the CLR of version 2.0. Which means it's not a complete new framework, but just an extension of 2.0, and it can't run without it.

In addition, it installs .NET Framework 2.0 SP1, (installs .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1) and .NET Framework 3.0 SP1  (installs .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 with 3.5 SP1).

This information came from [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_3.5)

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 [comes with .NET 3.5 by default.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions)

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the .net version i need to
>   install on windows 7

.NET Framework 3.5, including the SP1 mods, comes with Windows 7. At the time of this post, this is the latest version of the .NET Framework. (4.0 will be released next month.) Thus, you do not need to install anything.

If you are doing your development on a non-Windows 7 system, I would recommend that you install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on that system to minimize differences in the environments. (With this install, you can still down-target .NET Framework 2.0 since 2.0 through 3.5 use the same CLR runtime.)

Comment: +1 for including the SP1 - that is correct. It's .NET 3.5 SP1